# JWrapper app does not launch on OS X 10.7.5

Tags: macos, jwrapper

My 64-bit JWrapper application launches fine on OS X 10.8, 10.9 and 10.10, but not on 10.7.5.  I am using the latest verison of JWrapper (00031607960).  Here is the crash log:

```
Date/Time:       2014-10-28 09:33:26.025 -0700
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.7.5 (11G63)
Report Version:  9

Crashed Thread:  Unknown

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00007fff5fc01028

Backtrace not available

Unknown thread crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000055  rbx: 0x0000000000000000  rcx: 0x0000000000000000  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x0000000000000000  rsi: 0x0000000000000000  rbp: 0x0000000000000000  rsp: 0x0000000000000000
   r8: 0x0000000000000000   r9: 0x0000000000000000  r10: 0x0000000000000000  r11: 0x0000000000000000
  r12: 0x0000000000000000  r13: 0x0000000000000000  r14: 0x0000000000000000  r15: 0x0000000000000000
  rip: 0x00007fff5fc01028  rfl: 0x0000000000010203  cr2: 0x00007fff5fc01028
Logical CPU: 0

Binary images description not available


External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 1
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 431
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
```

Comment: Could you please include some more information when exactly the crash happens and ideally something minimal to reproduce the problem?

Comment: I don't have anything minimal but here is the app: [http://download.coinspark.org/SparkBit-0.9.2-beta-mac.dmg]. It crashes when you try to open it on 10.7.5 but is ok on 10.8, 10.9 and 10.10.