# JWrapper app crashes on all versions of OSX on load

Tags: java, javafx-8, jwrapper

I have a cross-platform Java app that I am deploying to Linux/Windows/OSX. Linux and Windows have been working fine for several months. I just went to test OSX, and I am finding that the JWrapper standalone offline launcher always crashes when I go to run the app (the install loading screen works and the proper JWrapper folders are created, however). Below is the log output from OSX and from my app regarding the crash. Looks like something memory related. No idea why this might be happening. Have tried disabling many advanced features of my app on startup to see if the crash goes away, to no avail.

OSX complains about this error:

> Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT)
>   Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000018
>   Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Pastebin for JWrapper log output: http://pastebin.com/tcjLzN6J
Pastebin for OSX log output: http://pastebin.com/KnzaqL8z

Note that the real app name has been replaced with "MyApp"

**UPDATE:** according to the following, this might just be due to the fact that I'm testing in vmware: http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8096072

Comment: Here is an unanswered question with the same issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26624703/jwrapper-app-does-not-launch-on-os-x-10-7-5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that JavaFX just "won't work" on VMware, no matter what. I tried my app on friend's Mac Book, and experienced no errors so I am fairly certain now that that was the problem.